# How to not reload an ASP page when posting a jQuery form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp-classic

Please bear with me, I'm a total novice.

What am I trying to do?
I'm trying to filter a list of courses from an input.

What is my environment? 
I'm working in a CMS coded in ASP and I don't have access to the server pages.
I can only insert some code in "modules" in the page and upload files on a FTP.
The pages are in XHTML 1.0 Transitional and I can't do anything about it.

My problem: 
This code works locally and on [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5632A/1/) but when I insert it in the sandbox all it does is to reload the page.

Here's the HTML I insert

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/searchCatalog.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/searchCatalog.css">
<form id="live-search" action="" class="styled" method="post">
<input type="text" class="search-field" id="filter" placeholder="What course are you looking for?" value="" />
<span id="filter-count"></span>
</form>
<ul class="courselist">
<li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">English course 1</a></li>
<li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">English course 2</a></li>
<li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">Spanish course 1</a></li>
<li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">Spanish course 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here's the JS I upload

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#filter').keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            // Hide the number of courses when nothing is entered in the search field
            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                $('#filter-count').hide();
            } else {
                $('#filter-count').show();
            }
            // Retrieve the input field text and reset the count to zero
            var filter = $(this).val(), count = 0;

            // Loop through the course list
            $(".courselist li").each(function () {

                // If the list item does not contain the text phrase fade it out
                if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
                    $(this).fadeOut();

                    // Show the list item if the phrase matches and increase the count by 1
                } else {
                    $(this).show();
                    count++;
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault();
            // Update the count
            var numberItems = count;
            $("#filter-count").text("Number of courses related to your search : " + count);
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: check your console for error

Comment: @A.Wolff Thanks for your reply but I've got no idea how to do that...

Comment: I'm talking about browser's console, press F12 inside your browser, refresh page and check for any error message

Comment: [blocked] The page at 'https://xxx.asp' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.

[blocked] The page at 'https://xxx.asp' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://malsup.github.io/jquery.blockUI.js': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.

Comment: I guess I'm gonna have to download the libraries and upload them on the server

Comment: @Aymericm, If you remove the http: portion and leave it at // then the scripts should load fine. However, I caution against referencing the latest jquery version, usually you want to target a specific version.

Comment: @mituw16, Thanks for your reply. I just tried and I've got no error for the code.jquery.com but the malsup.github.io doesn't seem to like the https.
I'm just gonna try to upload them on the FTP and we'll see.
Oh and it still reloads the page anyway for now...

Comment: @Aymeric ya, github is not a CDN, you have to use a local copy instead

Comment: Ok I removed the blockUI script for now as I don't even call anything from it anymore...
looks like //code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js loads just fine but now I got a 404 on the local searchCatalog.js js file.
Thanks for your help guys, I'm just gonna try to find out why I got this 404

Comment: I put the script directly in the page and it works, thanks a lot guys!
I'm still waiting on the CMS support to know why the link doesn't work but at least the functionality does!

Answer (score 2):

Change the script src to the following

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="//malsup.github.io/jquery.blockUI.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thx mituw16 that works for //code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js but as @A. Wolff said, it doesn't for //malsup.github.io/jquery.blockUI.js

That's ok, I just removed the latest.